# ms access 2007 lookup column select only still available records

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I have a table "Members" and a table "Books". To one member can belong many books but one book can belong to only one member, so I create a many to one relationship. I created an intermediate table "Owners".

I will put in the form "f_Members" a subform "f_Books" and in this I want to have for a field a lookup column with the list of all books. Now, for the first member I will choose let's say book1 and book2, then for the second member I want in the subform in the lookup column to be listed all books but with book1 and book2 greyed out and not possible to choose them anymore.

Is this possible in access 2007? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as a Many-To-One relationship, you do not need an intermediate table, rather add a Foreign Key in the Books table, refering to the Members' Primary Key.

It might be a bit more code for you to do this, but I would consider the following:

In f_Books, assign the recordset to be the [Books] table.
If you desire to show the already selected books grayed out, that would be easy to do with Conditional Formatting ([see here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/change-the-appearance-of-a-control-by-using-conditional-formatting-HA010208133.aspx)), with an expression like `Nz([books_fk_member_id]) <> ''`.

You can add a second condition to color the books already selected by this member with an expression like `Nz([books_fk_member_id]) = [Forms]![f_Members]![control_showing_member_id]`.

To make them not choosable, I think that the [Enabled] check button might do the trick for you, or you can write some code in vba, refering to `[Forms]![f_Members]![Form]![f_Books]![books_fk_member_id]` in order to identify the books' owner.

All that, given the fact that you choose to eliminate that extra table. If you don't the logic is the same, you just will have to use more complex conditions to get the same result.

Hope I helped.